# Responsive Polaroid Image with Unknown Image Dimensions

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive

I'm trying to create a gallery with a polaroid style to it. When the client uploads the images I won't know the size of the images, so I'm trying to scale the image to fit the box proportionally.

*(When images are uploaded, I do change the width or height to 760px via PHP but final dimensions are always unknown)*

I have it pretty much where I want it, but need it to be more responsive when it gets down to mobile size. Rather than scaling in width and height (like it should) the image goes off the canvas. Any help or other solutions would be appreciated.

**See Code: HTML**

```
<figure>
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/760/428/any" class="img-fill">
    <figcaption>Caption One</figcaption>
</figure>

<figure>
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/428/760/any" class="img-fill">
    <figcaption>Caption Two</figcaption>
</figure>
```

**CSS:**

```
figure{
  display:inline-block;
  height:350px;
  max-width:400px;
  min-width:300px;
  width:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
  border:10px solid white;
  border-bottom:none;
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0 4px 16px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 4px 16px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  box-shadow: 0 4px 16px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}
figcaption{
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  background:white;
  max-width:400px;
  min-width:300px;
  width:100%;
  height:40px;
  line-height:40px;
  text-align:center;
  font-family:'Permanent Marker', cursive;
  font-size:18px;
}

.img-fill {
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

**Code Pen:**

See the Pen [Responsive Polaroid Images](https://codepen.io/daugaard47/pen/RLbbeK/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi there is few possibilities:

1) use media query to solve the problem like

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
figure {
    max-width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 10px 20px
    }
}
```

2) or use relative size units like em or vw or vh or % to set width and height of figure